# HTTP form resets to default display

Tags: php, http

After the form is submitted, the drop-down displays the default blank value.

This form is part of the "edit profile" page on which users can edit their profiles on my website.

Is there any way for the drop-down to remain on the value that the user last selected?

So if the user is female, the drop down will continue to display "Female" even after she clicks the submit button.

```
<form method='post' action='profile.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<h3>I am a:</h3>
    <select name="sex">
    <option value = "">Select...</option>
    <option value = "female">Female</option>
    <option value = "male">Male</option>
</select>
```

Comment: read the current value from database and mark it as `selected` for example if female it would look like: `<option value="female" selected>Female</option>`

Comment: Thanks. Let's say the current value in the database is $sex. How would I display this as selected?

Comment: you can use a `if` statement to `echo 'selected';` to the given option if it matches for instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method='post' action='profile.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<h3>I am a:</h3>
    <select name="sex">
    <option value = "">Select...</option>
    <option value = "female"<?php if(strtoupper($user["sex"]) == "FEMALE") echo " selected"; ?>>Female</option>
    <option value = "male"<?php if(strtoupper($user["sex"]) != "FEMALE") echo " selected"; ?>>Male</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="sex">
<option value = "">Select...</option>
<option value = "female" <?php if($sex=='female') 
   echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Female</option>
<option value = "male" <?php if($sex=='male') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>
 Male</option>
</select>
```